# How do I add spaces between table view cells in swift or using the storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In the table view the cells are stuck without spacing how to make a space between cells in swift code or using the storyboard

thanks

Comment: Welcome. What is your code? See [ask] to complete your question and get great answers.

Comment: Hi I set everything on the storyboard and the code is template except numberOfSectionsInTableView , numberOfRowsInSection , cellForRowAtIndexPath and the default separator

Comment: You can't. You can fake it by increasing he height of he cells and making a blank bit of the cell. This will look like a gap.

Comment: then how can I make it with code I hope you help , thank you Mr.Fogmeister

Comment: -4 !  why do you treat me like this?

Comment: Perhaps, you can word your question a little bit better, and show the code that you've tried to use. Give us more information. Otherwise, you will be down voted and people will be less likely to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually its a bit tricky:
Set your cell height to something like lets say 75. set the background-color to clearColor. Then place a view with height of 50 on top of the cell and center it. Place your labels etc on that view. Dont forget the background-color for the view (maybe white?). If you do these steps, you will get a fake distance between the rows :)

Hope that will help you!

Answer (score 0):

What is your actual need? if your are willing to get larger cell then try increasing cell height, if your are talking about space between cells then you should fake out depending upon your need, if table view of your need is static , ie. if numbers of cell are constants then use sections that match your need, where you can add some space on section separator. If you post clear code sample then it would be more easy to discus !

Comment: It is dynamic and I need a spaces between cells as I mentioned .

Comment: Then you should use an empty label at the bottom of cell, it will provide you space between every cell !